# Map inside geoquery returns null

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, geolocation, geofire

I am trying to retrieve values from geoquery. The values are getting added to the map but when I return the values the map is empty.
Here `myPosition` is my position Latlng values that I am using for my location.
i have edited the question but still the problem is occuring the map is still empty

```
 private Map<String, GeoLocation> geoMap;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
 ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View view=  inflater.inflate
(R.layout.fragment_new_search2,  container, false);

 geoMap= new HashMap<>();
    readdata(new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(Map<String, 
        GeoLocation> geomap) {
        //    int size = geomap.size();
        }
    });
    int size = geoMap.size();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), 
    String.valueOf(size), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return view;
    }


 private void readdata(final MyCallback myCallback){
 DatabaseReference ref = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
  .child("WorkLocation");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(myPosition.latitude, myPosition.longitude), 2);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            geoMap.put(key,location);

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
    myCallback.onCallback(geoMap);

}

public interface MyCallback {
    void onCallback(Map<String, GeoLocation> geomap);
}
```

I tried a toast inside `onkeyentered` the values are there and they are getting added but still, the values are not returning to the method and the size of the map is still zero.

Comment: `addGeoQueryEventListener` callback methods are being invoked asynchronously

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method)

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Comment: @AlexMamo i have changed the code but still the size is zero is there still anything wrong with the code

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly i have changed the code can you please check it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All code that requires the data to have been loaded, must be inside (or called from inside) the `on...` method. So:

```
 DatabaseReference ref = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
  .child("WorkLocation");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(myPosition.latitude, myPosition.longitude), 2);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            geoMap.put(key,location);
            myCallback.onCallback(geoMap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) { }
        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) { }
        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() { }
        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) { }
    });

}
```

If you only want your `onCallback` to be invoked once all initial keys have been loaded through Geofire, put it in `onGeoQueryReady`:

```
 DatabaseReference ref = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
  .child("WorkLocation");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(myPosition.latitude, myPosition.longitude), 2);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            geoMap.put(key,location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) { }
        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) { }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
            myCallback.onCallback(geoMap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) { }
    });

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, is there any way i can loop through the map even if i put it inside onKeyEntered. i have asked it in another question can you please have a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877806/valueeventlistener-inside-for-loop

Comment: can you please look at it now i want to paginate the recycler view , i am confused as to how to do it if i have a map which contains the keys . it means i have to paginate the entries in  map now but i am confused as to how to do it

Comment: GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(myPosition.latitude, myPosition.longitude), 2); here in my readData method i am passing my values on predefined lattitude and longitude. how do i add a variable in this readData method