# Paginate the recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a map that i have retrieved from the geoquery and i am getting the values below to populate my recycler view . how can i paginate them any help please

```
    for (Map.Entry<String,GeoLocation> entry : geoMap.entrySet())
    {
      mWorkDatabase.child(entry.getKey()).addValueEventListener(new 
      ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            NewWork message = dataSnapshot.getValue(NewWork.class);

            messagesList.add(message);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
```

Comment: Get the database request out of the for loop. From you shared code, I see it doesn't help you at all.

Comment: i have resolved the dupllicate item issue for now i have another problem. i want to paginate these items. is there some way i can do that

Comment: i have changed the quesstion, what i am doing above is that i am getting a map from geoquery and getting only selected data into my recycler view. now i want to paginate them so that only 10 items displayed first and 10 on refreshing and so o